# Can't see the new boot menu on Mint Mate 19.3

Tags: linux-mint, grub, boot-menu

The patch notes of Mint 19.3 showed [this new boot menu](https://www.linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/tricia/grub.png). I've upgraded from 19.2. However I don't see the new boot menu but just the good ol' minimal GRUB. I even ran `sudo grub-update` but nothing changed. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing. There were a few packages that did not get automatically added when upgrading from 19.2, and the boot menu was one of them. The package you're looking for is **grub2-theme-mint**.